# TypeScript inference not working on nested generics, infers type as unknown

Tags: typescript, generics, higher-order-functions, inference, nested-generics

I need TypeScript to correctly infer the type T in the return value of my "wrongInference" function.

```js
interface Foo {
  bar: string;
}

const paramFunction = (bar: string): Foo => ({
  bar
});

type GenericFunction<T> = (...args: any) => T;

export const wrongInference = <T, F extends GenericFunction<T>>(
  paramFunction: F
) => ({
  data: {} as T,
});

const wrongType = wrongInference(paramFunction);
```

TypeScript infers the `data` value as unknown. Is there any way around this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could fix your problem with a conditional return type and the `infer` keyword:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
}

const paramFunction = (bar: string): Foo => ({
    bar
});

type GenericFunction<T> = (...args: any) => T;

export const wrongInference = <F extends GenericFunction<any>>(
    paramFunction: F
): F extends GenericFunction<infer T> ? { data: T } : never => ({
    data: {},
} as any);

const wrongType = wrongInference(paramFunction);
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/fr/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIBGcUAXMgM5hSgDmA3LgL664LojXIAOpcAW1QBXEAjDBOyALzIAFCXJUa9AJQUMWaQD55eQsVItVTXGACePFAHEIIaMAQixEzgB4AKrtlyAdP9I6Sgo4EHNVGV0PUwgADx50KDBkDi5kgHcoTjoASRAYaDskGWQ3VGQ4yBAAE0pkW3taJ1FxSRA3UPNtbTl8Qj4oQWdWzg1cdTQK2Kra+rsHZpc2t1ACqGQvZAB+HGRquDA4Cg9kZmQKewA3aEi9PoJ9w4psZgAaFmQ4Os6TNlTuTLZDyWFCyQEgXL5QpiCByAZDFquEAmIA)